# Problems with moving element CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to move element `h1` a bit down but without moving the whole `div` block.

HTML code is here:

```
<div class="mainblock"></div>
<div class="under"><h1>Some text</h1></div>
```

CSS rules is here:

```
.mainblock {
    margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
    width: 40%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

.under {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: coral;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font: 40px/30px Tahoma,sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 900;
    color: azure;
/*    Here I add some margin for H1   */
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

How can I move h1 tag only?
Using `padding` is not suitable because it adds some space and if it were a link it created some clickable space which I don't need.

Comment: Does `margin-top` work better than `padding` for you?

Comment: @fzzfzzfzz I need the same effect for moving h1 down but without creating some new space above it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position:relative`on the h1 element to move it without it affecting the position of any other elements.

```
h1 {
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    text-align: center;
    font: 40px/30px Tahoma,sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 900;
    color: azure;
    /*    Here I add some margin for H1   */
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move it by adding `line-height`

Comment: but how can I move it right or left then?(and it cause the same effect as padding(read about it in my question))

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility to achieve what you want is using positioning like so:

```
.under {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 40%;
height: 250px;
background-color: coral;
position:relative;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
font: 40px/30px Tahoma,sans-serif; 
font-weight: 900;
color: azure;
position:absolute;
top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Yep. Read about it yesterday. Good idea, but adding position:relative to h1 is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `padding-top` does what you want if the link is inside the `h1` tag.

HTML

```
<div class="mainblock"></div>
<div class="under"><h1><a href="#">Some text</a></h1></div>
```

CSS

```
.mainblock {
    margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
    width: 40%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

.under {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: coral;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font: 40px/30px Tahoma,sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 900;
    color: azure;

    /* replace margin-top with padding-top */
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle...I changed the padding from 20px to 60px to make it easier to see that there's no clickable space above the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/htpb9bdk/

Comment: Read the whole question before answering it.

Comment: @OfficialBAMM What part didn't I read; could you please be more specific? Are you referring to "Using `padding` is not suitable because it adds some space and if it were a link it created some clickable space which I don't need."? Because if I understood that correctly OP is saying that the space above the letters counts as part of the link, which is not true if the link is inside the `h1`.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the position:absolute to parent and child element 
try this : http://jsfiddle.net/heuek2za/

```
.mainblock {
    margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
    width: 40%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    margin-left:28%;

}

.under {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    width: 40%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: coral;
    margin-left:27%;
    margin-top:4%;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    font: 40px/30px Tahoma,sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 900;
    color: azure;
/*    Here I add some margin for H1   */
    margin-top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: we would have some problems with divs using absolute this way. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply float:left;width 100% to H1 which makes your margin to work.
The new CSS for h1 becomes:

```
    h1 {
         color: azure;
         float: left;
         font: 900 40px/30px Tahoma,sans-serif;
         margin-top: 20px;
         position: relative;
         text-align: center;
         width: 100%;
       }
```